# Run code only when a client connects to Meteor server?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Does meteor have a feature for doing something when a client connects to the server?

Comment: basically the whole idea of node.js is to "do something when client connects to server"

Comment: I meant instead of it running the code when the server starts, in my case, a SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [onConnection](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_onconnection) event to run code on the server when a new client connects.